# Reducing dimension of Tensor by pooling [Tensorflow]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to construct a neural network architecture with Tensorflow.

and I have a variable, type of Tensor.

Say,

```
a = <tf.Tensor shape(16, ?, 20) dtype=float32>
```

16 is batch size and an input is encoded into dimension of 20.
but, there are different number of inputs.

Here, how can I change its dimension to (16, 20) by just mean pooling with respect of the second dimension which has different size.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reduce_mean?

```
a = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=(16, None, 20))
b = tf.reduce_mean(a, axis=1)
print b
```

output:

```
Tensor("Mean:0", shape=(16, 20), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Exactly, what I want. Thank you